# Nonsigularity of non-strictly diagonally dominant matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We know that each strictly diagonally dominant matrice is nonsingular and If I'm not mistaken it's the same for the case of non strictly (on all the rows) diagonal matrices: when we have strictly dominance on all the rows, except on one row, where we have equality and $a_{i,i}≠0$ . How is it proved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $E_{ij}$ denote the matrix with an $i,j$ entry equal to $1$ and a $0$ everywhere else. Suppose that only the $i$th row fails the dominance condition, and consider any $j \neq i$. It follows that there exist $\alpha,\beta > 0$ and a diagonal matrix of the form
$$
D = I + (\alpha - 1)E_{ii} + (\beta - 1)E_{jj}
$$
for which the matrix $DAD^{-1}$ is strictly diagonally dominant.